# What is the metric and why a programmer should care ? - networking

Tags: c++, c, networking, p2p, metric

It's my understanding that by "metric" or "metrics" we describe the length ( in bytes right ? ) of a package traveling over the network, the problem is that as far as I know this value it's ISP related and it's almost impossible to find even 2 ISP with the same metric.

If I'm programming a P2P software to keep 2 software synced, and I would like to estimate what is the optimal size for my packets, does it makes sense to keep metrics in the count especially due to the fact that is an ISP related value and in the entire world there are a lot of ISPs ? I should apply some "heuristic algorithm" like assuming that the best metric is the lowest one and I just keep adding empty values for the padding on the longest one ?

Thanks.

PS
if you need a starting point for an example I would prefer something in C++ since i'm interested in this language at the moment.

EDIT:
a recap of the comments that you can find down below: looks like my question is too generic and now I'm focusing on MTU and latency ( lag ) to keep things more straight to the point.

Comment: More context, please. A "metric" is simply a measurement of some sort, and doesn't necessarily have anything to do with an ISP.

Comment: which metric are you referring to? there is a few important ones that come into play that yes a programer needs to be knowledgable of. If your referencing packet length's these are protocol dependedent ... eg. the max packet length and min. packet length for tcp vs. udp ... you definately need lots more context for this question

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta you mean a "use case" ? Kind of operative context ? Generally speaking i'm trying to keep some values synced, like, let's say, a couple of ints and floats, both the 2 users can modify this values and I'm trying to keep things synced with the lowest latency possible.

Comment: I'm sorry, @user2384250, that doesn't help.

Comment: @brendanmorrison see if my last comment helps, and yes, I think that I'm about to use TCP and/or UDP, the main problem is that often times the UDP ports are closed on the client router.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta what are the pieces that you need ? I'm focusing on TCP and UDP related technologies, this helps ?

Comment: @user2384250 You'll still have to explain what [metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metrics_(networking)) you're talking about.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson ok, I was thinking about the MTU for this question, but I was also assuming that the word "metric" wasn't" so "generic". In general terms I'm trying to also lower the latency.

Comment: ya it does... if your looking for low latency and just a few int's or char's per transmit , throw out tcp as setting up a tcp connections require's three packet transmissited before any data (lookup tcp handshake for more information on this) as for udp ports? what do you mean ports are ports there available for anytype of packet transfer you choose this is where firewall's come into place

Comment: @brendanmorrison the NAT policy on the router usually try to keep this UDP ports closed, as far as I know, also the example was about 2 ints, I'm planning to use more values and there are some critical part about latency and keeping the 2 clients really up-to-date.

Comment: @user2384250 okay if mtu is the "metric" (a very broad term) your worried about these are definately protocol specific again tcp will be far less optimal then udp for your tasks (unless you plan on keeping an open conection) and updates will be continually made

Comment: @brendanmorrison and what about the latency or the so called "lag".

Comment: @user2384250 ill write up an answer that will hopefully explain some of these things in a bit more depth and the tradoff's you will encounter

Comment: @brendanmorrison thanks, I was thinking about using 0mq as framework but I haven't really tried it, I'm saying this because if you want to propose some example this is my first choice right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Networking (and in particular inter-networking) is a relatively young science, not yet completely formed. Hence not all the "right behavior" is "shared" by anyone, simply because there are not all believing (or forced) to rein it "right".
The consequence is that anyone must -at some level- "care" of anything since it is never possible to have a full trust.

That said, to come close to your problem, let me start by telling you that you are yourself "unstrusted" since you use improper terminology.

You speak about networking "metric" (something, that, in networking science is related to *routing*) but you talk about something else, that is the MTU (Maximum Transfer Unit). If you speak to a network engineer that way, you almost sure you'll never find the answer to your question, simply because he will most likely understand another completely unrelated thing.

Now that everything is clear (I hope), lets understand a little bit of theory:

- Every transmission media, because of its very physics, introduce some errors.

  - At the link level this is mainly due to "electric noise" or to group dispersion, that makes the "signal" less and less intelligible.
  - At a circuit (or path, for connection-less network protocol, like IP) level this can be due packet loss due to congestion.
- The immediate consequence of the above points is that "an ***infinite*** end-to-end **correct** transmission" is not physically possible".
- To take care about this, both link protocols as well as transport protocols have to introduce some "redundancy check" (CRC) and some mechanism -in case the checksum fails- to recover the error. In this sense, the MTU is just the maximum number of bytes you can push into a packet without violating the underlying rules about how CRC are computed and the physical media managed.
- Depending on the application needs, IP offers different "transport protocols":

  - UDP is a "don't care": if a packet gets lost, the transport protocol will do nothing to recover
  - TCP is a "Full care, until a given time limit": if something gets lost, a retransission will be asked. All this is managed at the TCP/IP driver level, so the application is not required to take care, unless the "problem" last more than the timeout limit of a session.
- Independently on the TCP and UDP behavior, IP offer also a "fragmentation": if a transport unit is too long to fit a link protocol frame, the packed is split into more smaller ones. This process happens (at least in  theory) at every hop (every time you traverse a router to go from one link to another and another and another up t the final destination) and requires a complete reconstruction of the packet structure and CRC, hence it require more computational time and CPU power or routers that it will be normally required to just move a packet from port to another.

And this is why you have to take care: network performance are not the same for whatever packet length: longer packets into TCP requires less "waiting for acknowledge" time (so data transfer can flow faster), but longer packets requires longer latency in case of intermediate fragmentation, and more processing power on routers. (at the point that many ISP don't fragment: if it cannot go, they just discard, and let TCP to re-tune to a smaller MTU, or to the application to shorten its UDP packets).

In other word, if you don't care about performance, Just let TCP do do its job, and the data will somehow find a way to flow (by an intermediate fragmentation or by a and-to-end MTU negotiation). But if you want to maximize the performance, the less error-control-and recovery mechanisms you "stimulate" the less latency you get, and hence the more wide "segments" you get and hence the higher data rate you get.

There is an "optimal length" for every path you can have between the two endpoints you have to discover and respect if you want better performance.

If you use UDP, things are a bit worst: since there is no MTU negotiation and recovery, if a too long packet gets discarded along the way (because at a certain point it will no more fit a physical media, and the ISP is not going to fragment, to protect himself and other clients) you have to take care, and reduce its size, otherwise you will never be able to transfer it.

Feel free to retain the ISP is "unfair" to you, but consider that an excess of fragmentation activity can sit a router at the point no other transmission is possible from nowhere to no-one. And this is a damage higher than simply drop you flow.

Comment: my scenario it's about trying to calculate the optimal size of a packet to avoid that kind of fragmentation that you are talking about when mentioning CRC and CPU power. I also would like to have an idea about what this size can be because, eventually, I can rethink the content of my packet to fit the smallest possible size so I can optimize the latency as a consequence.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're probably talking about the metric from the routing tables. If so, it's just a number that reflects the 'cost' to the next hop, most probably in terms of latency, but it isn't a direct measurement in milliseconds. It's nothing a programmer needs to be concerned with.

Comment: so what are the values that I should care about considering this P2P application described from the previous comments ?

Comment: @user2384250 I've just stated that you don't need to care about these values. If there are other values you should care about, *you* need to tell *us* what they are.

Answer (score 1):

Okay with reguard's to optimizing updates with respect to Maximum Transmision Unit Size (MTU) you are going to want to stuff as many bits into a packet as possible to minimize number of packets sent accross the line. It should be noted that if your master machine (one which gets updates first) updates slowly you may decide to not wait for enough data to completely to reach MTU but to rather update the slave machine (machine your backing data up on). 
So as an example your logic may look something like this (in pseudo code)

```
while(keep_updating){

    if(new_data_size == (MTU - x)){  //really approximately equal to but smaller then the MTU 
      send_update_packet();

     }else if(count_time > max_wait_time){ // this will have to deal with min latency 
                                           // discussed below
         send_update_packet();
     }
   count_time++;  
}
```

Now the above examples is very dumb downed if this is something that your actuallly writing I assume it will be at the kernel level (not necessarily but nonetheless) this will more then likely be a single thread while the rest of you service is doing other thing's in each thread.

Now In terms of latency or lag time this is more specifically addressed as network delay something in a p2p situation you most likely don't have control of as it requires specific service agreement's with an ISP. However the sum of these parts will give an approximation of latency in general terms. ie. the time it takes from `send_update_packet();` until the slave machine receives the packet and your hook in the kernel/OS where you actual record the new updates.  Anyway's these will be the delay that are of interest to you

```
 Processing delay - time routers take to process the packet header
 Queuing delay - time the packet spends in routing queues
 Transmission delay - time it takes to push the packet's bits onto the link
 Propagation delay - time for a signal to reach its destination
```

... now as to which protocol you should choose again very dependent if you plan for the two machines to be talking all the time tcp may be your best it will prevent you from atleast ensuring that packet's are not lost (a luxury UDP handles at protocol's higher in the stack). If you expect updates to be more spread apart you will want to avoid TCP simply because of the TCP handshake process of opening a connection which will require 3x(the sum of delay's mentioned above) where as udp will allow you to send the packet's write away and then wait for a response on the same socket ensuring the packet was received correctly if you don't get a responce within time `x` retry.

As per the answer @EJP provided most of the time programers do not need to worry about this but at some level there are people worrying about this specifically in the cases of disaster management for Database server's and area like this where it is crucial that the DB's are as close to insync at all time's ... non the less that's my two sense after writing some kernel code last year that handle that specific problem Hope it helps!

Comment: last thing: for what I have seen even latency-critical application uses TCP as a sort of "compatibility" layer because often time UDP ports are blocked, but what means that a port is blocked from a programmer standpoint ? No communication at all ? I assume that I should also use some cross-platform framework if I want to simplify this tasks because networking is often time platform/kernel specific, am I right ? What about 0mq ( I use C++ ) ?

Comment: where are you using c++ at what level? os you should be okay.. i think? I used c but everything was linux so no platform issues, unfortunately cross-platform dev. is something I'm not to sure about.. if this is important you may want to look at a bit more abstract language but this is kind of all preference/use specific... If you find that udp is blocked on a router (which can be the case) tcp is a perfectly acceptable fallback (though as mentioned it does have limitations). However I'm doubting that in your case this latency will really be an issue so tcp can be used yes

Comment: I would really build up to worrying / optimizing for latency and packet size until you have the rest of the application built. Have the two machines stay in step (meaning close to in-sync) before worrying about all the thing's I mentioned ... basically crawl before you can walk. Though it is good to keep them in mind now it will save you some time down the road

Comment: @user2384250 take a good read of at Emilio Garavaglia answer he goes from broad into even more specificity about the problems with network engineering especially when you have no control of the network itself (ie. underlying hardware) It will give you a bit more insight into the problem of network engineering and optimization concerns